# Finding minimum value of a directional derivative(Multivariate Calculus)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x, y) = x
^2
e^{−y^2}$
and $v = (1, 1)$. Find all points $(x, y)$ where $|Dvf(x, y)|$
has its minimum value.

What i tried.

I know that im order to find the mimimum value of a directional derivative, i must first find the negative gradient.

negative gradient=$<-2xe^{-y^2},2yx^2e^{-y^2}>$

I then substitute $v=(1,1)$ to the above expression to get $(-2e^{-1},2e^{-1})$
Hence this is the point that i got. But im unsure whether it is correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks for any help

Comment: It is incorrect in a number of ways, both method and answer. I suggest you review your course a little, then perhaps come back with more specific questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to understand what $D_vf(x, y)$ means. It is a directional derivative, this means that given a vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ we take the derivation as a linear combination $v_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +v_2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. So if $v=(1,0)$ (resp.$(0,1)$) this simply means the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ (resp.$y$). So in our case we have $|Dvf(x, y)|= |-2xe^{-y^2}+2yx^2e^{-y^2}|$. And this is the value that has to be minimzed, thus we must find the points where the two partial derivatives of this quantity are zero.